# VB6 debugger like Numega SmartCheck

Tags: debugging, vb6, ollydbg

I've used to Numega SmartCheck tool for analyzing the VB6 applications to capture all events and memory access in Windows XP. But since I'm upgraded to Windows 8, I can't able to run any application and I'm getting access violation errors.

Well, I'm thinking of new and equivalent or better application. Which is the best debugger/emulator for them? PS: I'm using Ollydbg. So I expect some high level emulator/debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problem with VB6 applications on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7. In my case helped to disable of `DEP` (Data Execution Prevention) mechanism.

Please find the [walkthrough](http://windows8themes.org/how-to-disable-data-execution-prevention-in-windows-8.html) how to disable DEP on Windows 8.

Comment: Applications running smoothly in standalone mode. If I load in SmartCheck, I'm getting Access Violation error in Logs. And the DEP mod didn't helped to fix the problem.